# Book featuring an airplane plated with gold and an expedition to Africa to get it?

Tags: story-identification, books, military-sf

I didn't read the book, but listened to it in a series of radio auditions, in the end of 1980s. The book was in Polish translation, or, possibly, it was by Polish author.

More details, as I remember those:
The setting is in Africa, vaguely 1970s-ish (or 1980s, even?). Some country has recently driven off their dictator. For some reason there's a small group of special forces going in to get out the dictator's personal plane. They are armed with M16s and with some other kind of a (fictional?) assault rifle having 100 rounds in magazine.

Then the usual slog through the jungle ensues, and in the end they get the plane, but with a heavy plot twist. And the plane as it happens is coated with gold sheets and is very heavy and difficult to take off in and fly.

Comment: What is the science fiction or fantasy aspect of this story? A dictator coating things with gold is not unknown in our real world. Actually, being a dictator is not required for that.

Comment: Having all gold of the country ride on your plane rolled into sheets? ARs with 100 rounds? Looks like  a fantasy aspect all right.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to describe a work of science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: What community is proper for this question, then?

Comment: [100-round magazines for AR-15 rifles](https://gunmagwarehouse.com/kci-ar-15-223-5-56mm-100-round-gen-2-drum-magazine.html) actually exist, and while I don't know whether any super-wealthy person has gold-plated the outside of their airplane, they have certainly plated cars and boats, and filled the inside of airplanes and helicopters with gold-plated items. There is not much speculative technology here.

Comment: Not 'a several-molecules-thick layer of gold' but the whole gold reserve of the country put over the plane. And the '100 round AR' surely was set up as some futuristic thing (to the extent some guys declined using it).
Whatever. Where do I turn with this? Needless to say, I've already tried search engines.

Comment: Maybe [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Migrated to https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25072/book-featuring-an-airplane-sheet-plated-with-gold-and-an-expedition-to-africa-to